# My Touch 4g text in EditText is vertically centered too high

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a MyTouch 4g user that has submitted the following screenshots (sorry can't post images):

[Bad format](http://support.powertrade.com/attachments/token/xp3zl72ily2unj0/?name=IMG_0498.JPG)

Which is supposedly 480x800. Using 480x800 in the simulator all works fine:

[Good format](http://support.powertrade.com/attachments/token/8wwlvji9zygucvq/?name=device-2011-07-03-152003.png)

Here is the relevant xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow android:background="@drawable/gradient_row"
            android:paddingTop="4dip">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/outDiameterLabel" 
                android:paddingTop="6dip" 
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right" 
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:text="@string/outDiameterLabel" />
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/outExactDiameter"
                android:layout_height="40dip" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:focusable="false" 
                android:numeric="decimal" />
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/outRoundedDiameter"
                android:layout_height="40dip" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:focusable="false" 
                android:numeric="decimal" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It also appears to be off on the width. If you look at the inputs on the bottom notice how the last button on the right is truncated.  For the rest, the width is okay. I don't know how image was captured, it is 452 x 640.  His phone: HTC MyTouch 4G, Android 2.2.1, Kernel 2.6.32.21-g899d047, Build 1.17.531.2 CL277036 release-keys, Software Number 7.17.531.2 
Browser ver. WebKit 3.1. He has also tried un-install and re-install.

I cannot reproduce this on any device in my possession or in the emulator.  Other than buying or borrowing a myTouch 4g does anybody have any ideas for a fix?

Kevin

Comment: Judging by the fish-eye, your user likely took a picture of his phone on his desk at close range with another camera.  I wouldn't worry about the method of capture.   Wish I could help further.  If you link to your app I can test on my DroidX which is 854x480.  The only thing I can see is it seems the margin between layouts is a couple extra pixels on his device.

Comment: @Eric thanks for the offer but according to Android Market I have 423 Droid X users and nobody has complained. I think it's either a MyTouch 4G issue (0 users reported) or a problem with the users' setup. I have about 40 MyTouch 3G users and no complaints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 40dip is not an appropriate height for those fields and the text is getting clipped by the content bounds of the 9-patch background of the EditText. Your Spinner widgets above are getting similarly clipped in both screenshots, which is why the little down arrows to the right have strange shapes rather than a clean triangle.

There are two simple options available. You could relax your 40dip height restriction on the affected fields and use wrap_content instead. This is the easiest (and probably best) approach for your situation.

Alternatively you could create your own styles for the affected widgets, including your own 9-patches for focused, disabled, pressed, etc. states. This would let you guarantee that the visuals and metrics for the fields are compatible with your height restriction on all devices.

Comment: Based on your comments I tried adding  android:textSize="15dip" to the EditText which is the same as what I have on the label which btw  looked fine that should have been my clue.  The text is now centered better but smaller.  I am going to push out this change and hopefully it will solve the problem.  What threw me was it only was happening on one device. Thanks. Kevin

Comment: No problem. Different devices may have different defaults for things like that. The best way around it for now is to either enforce metrics yourself or let the system measure and flow elements to the sizes they want to be. Getting stuck in the middle causes heartache. :)